# 'onChange' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

Im Learning ReactJs ... I want Design a Form (Like Section Exprience in Linkedin) with React Hook Form, Material Ui and TypeScript.

I Faced a Error with this text: 'onChange' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.

my function in onChange, doesn't work. I want to register with react hook form. how can I solve this error?

```js
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";

// React Hook Form Types
type Inputs = {
  title: string;
  employment: string;
  company: string;
  location: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  description: string;
};

function ExprienceCreate() {
  const [employment, setEmployment] = useState("");

  // React Hook Form
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Inputs>();

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (data) => console.log(data);

  // Function For Employment Type Select
  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setEmployment(event.target.value as string);
    console.log(employment);
  };

  console.log(watch("title")); // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: "414px",
        border: "1px solid #000",
        p: 2,
        borderRadius: 1,
        margin: "16px auto",
      }}
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Typography sx={{ my: "12px" }}>Title:</Typography>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Ex: Sales Manager"
          fullWidth
          {...register("title")}
          sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        ></TextField>
        <Divider />
        <Typography sx={{ my: "12px" }}>Employment type:</Typography>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Employment Type</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={employment}
          label="Employment Type"
          onChange={handleChange}
          {...register("employment")}
          sx={{ mb: 2, width: "100%" }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"full"}>FullTime</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"part"}>PartTime</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        <Divider />
        <Typography sx={{ my: "12px" }}>Company name:</Typography>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Ex: Microsoft"
          fullWidth
          {...register("company")}
          sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        ></TextField>
        <Divider />
        <Typography sx={{ my: "12px" }}>Location:</Typography>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Ex: London, United Kingdom"
          fullWidth
          {...register("location")}
          sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        ></TextField>
        <Divider />
        <Typography sx={{ my: "12px" }}>Date:</Typography>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Ex: Sales Manager"
          fullWidth
          {...register("startDate")}
          sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        ></TextField>
        <TextField
          placeholder="Ex: Sales Manager"
          fullWidth
          {...register("endDate")}
          sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        ></TextField>
        <Divider />
        <Typography sx={{ my: "12px" }}>Description:</Typography>
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          {...register("description")}
          sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        ></TextField>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ExprienceCreate;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Anastasia's answer is not correct, because that way you will overwrite `react-hook-form`'s `onChange` - so this will it prevent from updating it's internal form state and therefore the current value won't be available in your `onSubmit` callback.

If you need to have an `onChange` callback for `register` you can provide a callback in the config options, which you can pass a second argument. Check the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) for more infos.

But i guess the `useState` for the "employment" field is not needed here as you could just access the current value in your `onSubmit` callback. If you need to access it before submitting then you could use `watch` as you did with the "title" field.

**Using `onChange` config option**

```js
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  label="Employment Type"
  {...register("employment", { onChange: handleChange })}
  sx={{ mb: 2, width: "100%" }}
>
```

**Using `watch`**

```js
const employment = watch('employment');
```

```js
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  label="Employment Type"
  {...register("employment")}
  sx={{ mb: 2, width: "100%" }}
>
```

Answer (score 1):

`register` probably overwrites the `onChange` you have specified. Try swapping the order of `onChange` and `register`.

```
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={employment}
      label="Employment Type"
      {...register("employment")}
      onChange={handleChange}
      sx={{ mb: 2, width: "100%" }}
    >
```